# Needed. JavaScript 3D framework with precise timestamps for frame rate and keyboard events

Tags: javascript, 3d, vertical-sync

I am happy with THREE.js, but for my project I should know for each frame was it presented in time (for 60Hz each 16.67 ms) or not. THREE.js statistic is average. I also want to be know which button and when was pressed with high precision. This should not be a web application. It is ok if i will run it in a local node.js or something like this.

**Could you help me with such framework? (I need link to framework or to good explanation how to do it THREE.js/babylon.js**

Comment: Take a look at [window.performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) for high precision timing. Keypress should already be precise and you can log events easily using the `code` attribute of a [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babylon.js support deterministic lock step: http://doc.babylonjs.com/babylon101/animations#deterministic-lockstep
Could it be something that can help you?

Also you can check the instrumentation tool that give you average and live data:
http://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/optimizing_your_scene#instrumentation